# Can I use one PARTITION definition for multiple window function calls?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, window-functions, partition-by

This is my query. I use the same window function `sum()` with the same partition definition for 14 result columns:

```sql
select id,weekly,
  sum(totalsteps) OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_steps, 
  sum(totaldistance) OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_distance,
  sum(veryactiveminutes) OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_veryactive,  
  sum(fairlyactiveminutes) OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_fairlyactive, 
  sum(lightlyactiveminutes) OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_lightlyactive, 
  sum(totalsteps)  OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_steps,
  sum(totaldistance) OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_distance, 
  sum(veryactivedistance) OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_veryactivedistance, 
  sum(moderatelyactivedistance) OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_moderatelyactivedistance, 
  sum(lightactivedistance) OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_lightactivedistance,  
  sum(sedentaryactivedistance) OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_sedentaryactivedistance, 
  sum(calories) OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_calories, 
  sum(totalminutesasleep) OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_asleep, 
  sum(totaltimeinbed)  OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly) as total_inbed
from (select *, date_trunc('week', activitydate) as weekly
  from activitysleep_merged 
  ) as weeklysum
```

Do I have to spell out `OVER (PARTITION BY id, weekly)` with each sum?
Is there better way to re-write my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `WINDOW` Clause, The optional WINDOW clause has the general form

> WINDOW window_name AS ( window_definition ) [, ...]

Then use `OVER` window_name for your aggregate function, it might be more elegant

```
 select id,weekly,
    sum(totalsteps) over w as  total_steps, 
    sum(totaldistance) over w as  total_distance,
    sum(veryactiveminutes) over w as  total_veryactive, 
    sum(fairlyactiveminutes) over w as  total_fairlyactive, 
    sum(lightlyactiveminutes) over w as  total_lightlyactive, 
    sum(totalsteps) over w as  total_steps,
    sum(totaldistance) over w as  total_distance,
    sum(veryactivedistance) over w as  total_veryactivedistance, 
    sum(moderatelyactivedistance) over w as  total_moderatelyactivedistance, 
    sum(lightactivedistance) over w as  total_lightactivedistance, 
    sum(sedentaryactivedistance) over w as  total_sedentaryactivedistance, 
    sum(calories) over w as  total_calories, 
    sum(totalminutesover w as leep) over w as  total_over w as leep, 
    sum(totaltimeinbed) over w as  total_inbed 
from (
    select *, date_trunc('week', activitydate) as weekly
    from activitysleep_merged 
) WINDOW w AS ( PARTITION BY id, weekly );
```

more detail we can refer [WINDOW Clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html)

[SQLfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=83ebd33825c8cb139168d68a461ca130)

Comment: Hi I tried but it reminds me:'syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 27:     sum(totalsteps) w as  total_steps, '

Comment: I miss the `OVER` clause, I edited it

Comment: Thanks! I got it, but I got a lot of replicates for each id. How can I remove those replicates? Have Distinct() in front of each sum query?

Comment: I guess you might want to use `GROUP BY` with aggregate function instead window aggregate function, but there isn't any sample data I am not sure

Comment: Inspired by you, I use 'GROUP BY' function and it works.  I also learn 'window' function. You're amazing! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi I have another question. I want to label each id by adding a column, for example, if total very_active minutes is greater than 60, then label the user as 'very active'. How can I achieve this with the query I wrote? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [WINDOW clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WINDOW).

```sql
SELECT id, weekly
     , sum(totalsteps)    OVER w AS total_steps
     , sum(totaldistance) OVER w AS total_distance
     , ...
FROM  (SELECT *, date_trunc('week', activitydate) AS weekly FROM activitysleep_merged ) AS weeklysum
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id, weekly);   -- !
```

You still have to repeat the `OVER` keyword, but can replace the actual definition of the partition with the identifier declared in the `WINDOW` clause.

This is a syntax shortcut, **no effect on performance**. Postgres will re-use the same partition in either case.

Related:

- [Rolling sum / count / average over date interval](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107495/3684)

#### Aggregation?

That said, your query suspiciously looks like you do **not** want window functions to begin with, but **plain aggregation**. While being at it, you don't really *need* that subquery either:

```sql
SELECT id, date_trunc('week', activitydate) AS weekly
     , sum(totalsteps)    AS total_steps
     , sum(totaldistance) AS total_distance
     , ...
FROM   activitysleep_merged
GROUP  BY 1, 2   -- !
ORDER  BY 1, 2   --  or BY 2, 1 ?
```

And you'll want the result ordered.

This produces a single (aggregated) row per `(id, weekly)` - as opposed to your original query, which returns one row per input row.

I threw in positional references as syntax shortcut, since this question was about short syntax. Related:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Yes! I changed my query and it works! Thank you thank you!